# Python unittest not contradictions

Tags: python, python-unittest

so I would like to test a code snippet that I know would work:

```
def find_primes(n):
    primeList = []
    for x in range(2, n+1):
        for y in range(2, x):
            if x % y == 0:
                break
        else:
            primeList.append(x)
    print(primeList)
```

This is to find prime number list in a specific rage from 2 to whatever I want.
In this case, if I try `find_primes(10)`, I will get `[2, 3, 5, 7]`

But when I try the unittest:

```
import unittest
class PNumTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_find_prime_number(self):
        self.assertEqual(find_primes(10), [2, 3, 5, 7])

unittest.main()
```

it shows:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7]
[2, 3, 5, 7]
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_find_prime_number (__main__.PnumTEST)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in test_find_prime_number
    self.assertEqual(find_primes(10), [2, 3, 5, 7])
AssertionError: None != [2, 3, 5, 7]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s
```

I am trying to understand what went wrong.

Comment: your function returns None.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre But why?

Comment: because you're printing the result, but not returning it. that's why.

Comment: try adding "return primeList" at the end of your function after the print statement.

Comment: Got it............